# Accessing previous definition / reference of dot (.) in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I reference a full row in print function in the following code:

```
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate_at(vars(cols),
            funs({ print(<REFERENCE_FULL_ROW_HERE>); . }))
```

Where `cols` is vector of column names, which I want to change.

Comment: This seems very much like an XY problem. I don't think there's any (good) way to do exactly what you're asking for. But if you tell us the bigger picture problem, I think we can help you solve it.

Comment: What exactly is your desired output?

Comment: I've almost solved it with `.data` pronoun, but I cannot reference all the columns I need with `.data[[cols]]`, it gives me an error.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `pmap` or `pwalk` from the `purrr` package. I find this [repo about row-oriented workflows](https://github.com/jennybc/row-oriented-workflows/blob/master/ex09_row-summaries.md#how-to-use-an-arbitrary-function-inside-pmap) incredibly helpful for such problems.

If you only want to call the function for its side-effect and don't want to store the return value, you can use the solution using `pwalk`. If you want to store the return value use `pmap` inside a `mutate` call.

```r
library(tidyverse)

pwalk(
  head(mtcars, n = 5),
  function(...) {
    cols <- list(...)
    print(paste(cols$cyl, cols$mpg))
  }
)
#> [1] "6 21"
#> [1] "6 21"
#> [1] "4 22.8"
#> [1] "6 21.4"
#> [1] "8 18.7"

cars_wrangled <- mtcars %>%
  mutate(
    result = pmap(
      .,
      function(...) {
        cols <- list(...)
        paste(cols$cyl, cols$mpg)
      }
    )
  )

head(cars_wrangled)
#>    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb result
#> 1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4   6 21
#> 2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4   6 21
#> 3 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 4 22.8
#> 4 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 6 21.4
#> 5 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 8 18.7
#> 6 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 6 18.1
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>